# What's the point of the watch timer?

Tags: worms-crazy-golf

One of the power-ups in *Worms Crazy Golf* is a watch that has 10 seconds on it.  If you click it after you've hit the ball, everything slows down.  As far as I can tell, that's *all* it does.  Everything plays out normally, just slower.  Is there a point to this?  Something I can do while time is slowed?

(I verified that the level clock keeps running while in slow-mo.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it does anything else, but it looks like it enhances any spin you've put on the ball, allowing it to curve further in mid-air than it would otherwise.  If you're trying to curve around something the better option is the parachute, so this is still sort of pointless.